# How to change letters of a word at specific positions and obtain all the possible combinations after substitution of new letters?

Tags: replace, combinations

I want to mutate a sequence of letters by changing certain letters at specific locations by using python. If my initial sequence is s='abcdefghij' and I want to replace letters at position 1,3,5,7 with letters from a list list=[klmnop] so that I could get all possible combinations

s = 'bcde'

final = []

if s[0] == 'b':

```
final = ['{}{}'.format(i, s[1:], s[:3]) for i in 'moon']
```

print(final).

I tried this but it can substitute only one letter, how can I substitute multiple letters of a word.

Comment: Permutations and combinations are different things. Please clarify your question.

Comment: What language are you using?